# Browser-process using high CPU

Tags: 14.04, cpu, browser, process, cpu-load

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Having just transited from Windows to Linux, I'm completely new to process and service management, in this OS.

One or more processes frequently stack my CPU usage up high, sometimes even up-to 100%. This time _ found that the process called Browser-process is the culprit. Here's how it appears on System Monitor

[image: high CPU load]

Although the process still runs after I stopped it, it no longer gulps down the CPU. Is it usual for a process to soak up all the resources as such?

My other concern is that the CPU usage is consistently always high when compared to Windows-based systems, where the system used to be idle for extended periods with apparently "0" CPU usage. So, is that really what happens in Windows?

Comment: Please tell us you cpu and gpu.

Comment: Its a CPU in the image but i do have dedicated AMD graphics card pre-installed.

Comment: Well, my second part of the question is more about processes being more resource exhaustive mainly the Firefox browser, or is it just casual that, here in the Linux, performance is a core priority?